# SiriKit Intents UI - Payment Domain Remove “Amount” bar at bottom

Tags: ios, sirikit

I'm trying to create a custom UI for my SiriKit extension in the Payments domain. However, the UI shows amount field at the bottom of the "send payment" card.  Is it possible to remove it?